# How to get color bar or legend from scatter() in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot from `matplotlib` that uses data from a Pandas data frame. I used one column of `int`s for my colors variable, but I don't know how to show what each color means. How do I extract the color code?

```
f_trains.plot.scatter("Latitude", "Longitude", color = f_trains['LstPrice'])
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach should work.

In the call `.plot.scatter()`:

- Use `c=` instead of `color=` to tell matplotlib you want to use colormapping
- Use `cmap=` with one of matplotlib's [colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html) to tell which colors you want; setting the number of colors in the colormap will give a colorbar with separations (instead of a continous one)
- Set `colorbar=False`, so we can create the colorbar separately
- Set `vmin=` and `vmax=` to the lowest and highest color number and extend by a half; this will put the tick positions nicely in the center of each color
- Grab the `ax` that is output by `ax = ....plot.scatter(...)`

Then, create the colorbar. It needs a "scalar mappable", this is the matplotlib element that stores the scatter dots with their color information. In this case, it is stored in `ax.collections[0]`. The colorbar can then be accessed to set the ticks and their labels.

Here is some test code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# a dummy dataframe for testing
f_trains = pd.DataFrame({"Latitude": np.random.normal(0.1, 1, 100).cumsum() + 5,
                         "Longitude": np.random.normal(0.1, 1, 100).cumsum() + 5,
                         "LstPrice": np.random.randint(1, 12, 100)
                         })

# suppose the correspondence between the integers and the labels is given in a dictionary
lstPrice_dict = {1: '1000-2000', 2: '2000-3000', 3: '3000-4000', 4: '4000-5000', 5: '5000-6000', 6: '6000-7000',
                 7: '7000-8000', 8: '8000-9000', 9: '9000-10000', 10: '10000-11000', 11: '11000-12000'}

num_colors = len(lstPrice_dict)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('RdYlBu', num_colors)
ax = f_trains.plot.scatter("Latitude", "Longitude", c=f_trains["LstPrice"], cmap=cmap,
                           vmin=min(lstPrice_dict.keys()) - 0.5, vmax=max(lstPrice_dict.keys()) + 0.5,
                           colorbar=False)
cbar = plt.colorbar(ax.collections[0], ax=ax)
cbar.set_ticks(list(lstPrice_dict.keys()))
cbar.set_ticklabels(lstPrice_dict.values())
cbar.ax.set_title("LstPrice", ha='left')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: pandas scatterplot with colorbar legend]